# Web Page UI Testing Tools/Framework

Tags: testing, web-applications

I would like to test some web pages UI.  Ideally I'd like to use the browser to navagate to a page and perform some interactions and the testing platform/software record what's happening into C# test so I can then programatically change some of the input parameters, and then test that certain HTML elements meet my assertions.

I'm using VS 2008 but will be upgrading VS 2010 in the future, integration with Visual Studio would be nice but not necessary.

Can anyone recommend any testing software that meet's these simple requirements and doesn't cost the earth.

Comment: Wow, lot's of feedback that's great, my first application I need to test is some Microsoft CRM customisations, this requires IE :( so I'll take a look through the response with this in mind.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to use Selenium, I've tried using Selenium for .Net.

Comment: but getting this to run the tests with-in Visual Stuido, even with Gaillo and Resharper.  It seems that I still can't find a good fit for recording and testing web pages in IE and being able to edit them in C sharp and run them through VS.  I must be missing sometihng, surly this should be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is definitely worth a look. They have a small IDE that you can use to record a test, though you will find that you get more value and more robust tests if you code them yourself. [Watin](http://watin.org/) is just as good in my opinion as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Selenium looks good but the no IE recorder is an issue for me personally.  Watin, has a recorder for IE and seems fairly simple so it meets my requirements.  I'll try this out initally

Comment: After playing with Watin for most of the day it has some issues, while it seemed ok initially (after having to check the code and and recompile it to get it to work on 64bit OS) I've now dumped this as an option, I was getting too many crashes (it is in Beta)

Comment: I've ended up with Selenium Toolkit for .Net, although it does not meet all my requirements it's the best fit for me at this point.

Comment: Selenium2 or WebDriver is in beta or release candidate stages, Selenium 1 has been about for a while now and is pretty stable.

Comment: The final choice was the WebDriver is simple and works a treat

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [robot framework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/), with the [SeleniumLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/). Robot framework is a keyword-based testing framework that is written in python. It allows you to write test cases in plain text or as html tables. SeleniumLibrary is an extension that lets you script web pages with keywords like `Open Browser`, `Click Link`, `Checkbox Should Be Selected`, etc.

Comment: +1 Robot framework is quite good and its community is growing very fast.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it does look like a bit of a leaning curve for me.  I'm a .Net guy and python's not in my bag at the moment.  I think I want something a bit more simple, I just want to install it and use a UI to record tests to start with, not a commmand line fan.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is kind of the "de-facto" tool for web testing. If you use a BDD framework on top such as Cucumber it becomes even nicer. If you want to write the cucumber steps in .net, you can use [Cuke4Nuke](https://github.com/richardlawrence/Cuke4Nuke)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Selenium does seem like an excellent platform.  I really wanted to record test's and if I could use unfortunately it has to be with IE, sorry for not being more specific.  BDD/Cucumber looks cool but I'm not at that point.

Comment: I've ended up with Selenium Toolkit for .Net, although it does not meet all my requirements it's the best fit for me at this point.

Comment: Selenium Toolkit for .Net does not use the new Selenium web driver so that was a bit of a red herring.  Selenium WebDriver is very simple and just works by referencing the C# assembly. I'm going to look at Cucumber / Cuke4Nuke / NSpek and SpekFlow to sit what suits.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to test your code from a developer perspective using a framework called [CAT](https://www.npmjs.org/package/catjs). This framework offers annotation driven testing that you can add to your code. It then can be played on your natural environment such desktop or mobile devices with its runner.
It's a new approach but you might find it helpful. Read about it in [here](http://catjs.blogspot.co.il/2014/03/testing-is-good-i-have-created-too-many.html).